# Why i have a little space in my background position

Tags: php, css

First please look to the picture to know what different

[Sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4bNk.png)

my css & html is like this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .bg-product {
    background-image: url(../../assets/img/home/mobile/3.png);
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 px-0">
  <a href="<?php echo site_url($link_product)  . $link ?>" class="link-default">
    <h2 class="h5 product-background">
      <?php echo $value->item_name; ?>
    </h2>
    <p class="my-0 product-background">
      <?php
        if ($value->item_discount != 0 ) {
     ?>
        <strike class="text-discount product-background"><?php echo currency_display($value->$price); ?></strike>
        <?php
         if($value->item_discount >= 10) {
      ?>
          <span class="text-nowrap product-background"><?php echo $value->item_discount . '% Off' ?></span>
          <?php
          }
       ?>
            <?php
             }
       ?>
    </p>
    <p class="price-product bg-product">
      <?php
        if ($value->item_discount != 0 ) {
            echo currency_display($value->$price - ($value->$price * ($value->item_discount/100)));
        }else {
            echo currency_display($value->$price);
        }
     ?>
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
```

its for mobile version, i have some problem why i have space like that in my view, where i call a function for discount price , the space is apear between the real price and discount prince

Comment: This is primarily a client-side problem, so please show client-side code as well - no one here has your server-side setup or your data available to make that PHP code you have shown reproduce your exact output.

Comment: Please put the HTML code of your generated PHP, that will help better understanding the code. The CSS of parent/child elements will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `background-size: cover` -

```
.bg-product {
    background-image: url(../../assets/img/home/mobile/3.png);
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
}
```